# how to load/update images after scrolling up and down in grid view running in backgroung(async task)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-asynctask

I'm working on displaying multiple groups of images.I'm using list view for displaying each group.Inside each group there will be one text view, check box and grid view.
In grid view, i have to display each images of corresponding group.
Here is my Listview adapter class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Context listapadptercontext;
    private List<IndividualGroup> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    GridViewAdapter mAdapter;
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context _c,List<IndividualGroup> _listdata){
        this.listapadptercontext = _c;
        this.listData = _listdata;
        this.layoutInflater =  (LayoutInflater) listapadptercontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_heading, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grpcheckbox);
            holder.myGridView = (MyGridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        IndividualGroup individualGroup = listData.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText("Set" + (position + 1));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(listapadptercontext, 4);
        mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(listapadptercontext,0,individualGroup.getIndividualgrpofdupes());
        holder.myGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//        IndividualGroup individualGroup = listData.get()
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        MyGridView myGridView;
    }
}
```

My Gridview adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceId, List<String> data) {
        super(context,layoutResourceId,data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_duplicate_image, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            holder.image = (SquareImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_duplicate_image);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.individualcheckbox);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        String item = data.get(position);
        if (holder.image != null) {
            new GridviewLoader(context,holder.image).execute(item);
        }
        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        SquareImageView image;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        ViewHolder(View view){
//            super(view);
            image = (SquareImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_duplicate_image);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.individualcheckbox);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//            ImageItem imageItem = data.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

My gridviewloader(Async task):

```
public class GridviewLoader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    Context imageloadercontext;

    public GridviewLoader(Context c,ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        this.imageloadercontext = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
//        CommonlyUsed.logmsg("%%%%%%------Filepath: "+params[0]);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapLoader.loadBitmap(params[0], 100, 100);
        return bmp;
    }

//    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rsz_empty_photo);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is images are displaying initially. but after scrolling down,it disappear. And it take too much time to load again.
Here are my layouts:

Inside listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/linearLayoutStyleNoBgColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/deepyellow">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/textFieldStyleType1WithCheckbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <CheckBox
            style="@style/checkboxStyleType1"
            android:id="@+id/grpcheckbox"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_duplicate_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox" />
    </LinearLayout>

<!--        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_duplicates"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>-->



    <com.xxx.xxx.customviews.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Inside grid view :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imagelayout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.remodupes.remoactivities.customviews.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_duplicate_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/individualcheckbox"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_duplicate_image"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_duplicate_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So how can i solve this problem.

Comment: image downloading, loading, caching and displaying is way more complex than that. Just use a library that already implements all for you, such as Glide or Picasso (as suggested by Ajay answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to load image with a list you can use image loader or picasso

for picasso i suggest you [blog for your problem](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/)  you can use it like after add [jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpicasso200jar.htm) of picasso into your module

```
  Picasso.
   with(State.mainContext).
   load(parseImageFile.getUrl()).
   into(null);
```